# PDE: Laplace equation Maximum Principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

The maximum priciple for Laplace equation assumes, in both PDE textbooks by Fritz John and Lawrence Evans, that the domain of the harmonic solution be bounded.  Is the maximum priciple still valid if the domain is unbounded?

Comment: There is research done on this topic. I'm not familiar with this stuff, so I won't summarize it here. E.g. try this

https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDAQFjABahUKEwi8-IWZ7ZfJAhWLchQKHbegBdM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownloads.hindawi.com%2Fbooks%2F9789775945389%2Fart109.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE63SD5WuNO6jpkyM3_bH7qFKaMKQ&sig2=AnREpXer211Akq1-MnHymA